# Problem in using DataSet 

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net, dataset

I have first manually created a `DataSet` in my project name `recvd.xsd` having corresponding `recvd.xss`. On my button click event i have done the following coding.

```
try 
{
    DataSet recvd_REPORT = new DataSet();
    DataTable REPORT = new DataTable();
    String dd_webCofig = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["server2"].ConnectionString;
    OdbcConnection ddlistconn = new OdbcConnection(dd_webCofig);
    ddlistconn.Open();

    REPORT = recvd_REPORT.Tables["REPORT"];
    DataColumn myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
    myDataColumn.DataType = typeof(System.Int32);
    myDataColumn.ColumnName = "RECEIVED";
    myDataColumn.ReadOnly = false;
    myDataColumn.Unique = false;
    // Add the Column to the DataColumnCollection.
    REPORT.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);

    string query = "SELECT case_no as \"RECEIVED\" from dcpanaji.Civil_t where dt_regis > '" + txtStartDate.Text + "' AND dt_regis < '" + txtEndDate.Text + "' AND court_no = " + DropDownList1.SelectedItem + "";
    Response.Write(query);
    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(query, ddlistconn);
    OdbcDataReader loginMyReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    OdbcDataAdapter adptr = new OdbcDataAdapter(query, ddlistconn);
    adptr.Fill(REPORT);

    ddlistconn.Close();   
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write(ex.Message);
}
```

I am getting the error as

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

If i remove `as \"RECEIVED\"` from my SQL query and simply execute my SQL query than the result of my query is as follows (varies depending on user input)

`200200000452011` ......, n numbers of 12 digit number.

Please help me to remove the error as to why am i not able to bind to DataTable.

I am getting the error before `Response.Write(query);` is executed, why is that problem?

I removed the try catch block and now i get the error as

[image]

Comment: Yes i did that now, but still got the same error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: In what string have you your error?

Comment: What database engine do you use? SQL Server? MySQL? Else?

Comment: @Ajay, abatishchev i am getting error before my Response.Write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
SELECT case_no as `RECEIVED` ...
```

or just

```
SELECT case_no as RECEIVED ...
```

---

Anyway the correct DataSet filling code should look like this:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
using (OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(sqlQuery, connection)
using (OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(command)
{
    adapter.Fill(ds);
}
```

Comment: That might be correct in case query is wrong  but error is before that, as my Response.Write is not getting executed.

Comment: Ya your code works fine there is no problem in it, I am designing REPORT and the DataSet i have designed manually should hold the result and that particular column i have dragged into my report.How to check dataset contents?

Comment: @Ishan: `REPORT = recvd_REPORT.Tables["REPORT"];` can return null before `Fill()` so `REPORT.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);` throws the exception. Check that. P.S. Unfortunately I have no access to email during worktime

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL instead of \"RECIEVED\" have you tried just RECIEVED, no quotes?

Comment: That might be correct in case query is wrong  but error is before that, as my Response.Write is not getting executed.

Comment: If your response.write is not executed, then something before that try section has failed.

Comment: There is nothing before try. On button click there is only try catch which i have posted above. There is no other code above or below it.

Answer (score 0):

You need not to use \"RECEIVED\" in the query, you can use like below.

```
query = "SELECT case_no as [RECIEVED] from dcpanaji.Civil_t where dt_regis > '" + txtStartDate.Text + "' AND dt_regis < '" + txtEndDate.Text + "' AND court_no = " + DropDownList1.SelectedItem + "";
```

Comment: That might be correct in case query is wrong  but error is before that, as my Response.Write is not getting executed.

Answer (score 0):

you can write query as like

```
query = "SELECT case_no as RECIEVED from dcpanaji.Civil_t where dt_regis > '" + txtStartDate.Text + "' AND dt_regis < '" + txtEndDate.Text + "' AND court_no = " + DropDownList1.SelectedItem + "";
```

check like that....

Comment: That might be correct in case query is wrong  but error is before that, as my Response.Write is not getting executed.